# Reusing/Recycling Hard Disk space on PS3

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I was thinking about buying a Playstation 3 for myself, but got confused with the HD spaces. I read some questions on Gaming SE and they suggest that using something as big as 500 is more than sufficient. However, it is possible to upgrade the HD as it's just a fancy PC with Sony software and a 2.5" HD for data storage. My budget is a bit tight, so trying to compromise where I ideally can.

Because it is an HD and I can choose which game I can have, isn't it possible to remove old game data (i.e. the games that I have saved data for, but not been playing for a while) and free up space like we usually do in our PCs? For example, if I am not playing FIFA 2012 now, but want to play Destiny - could I not erase FIFA 2012 data and use free space for Destiny? P.S. I know that the PS3 OS will consume some space, so Ideally I will be getting something like 75% of the advertised space e.g. 8GB in a 12GB console?

Target games - I will probably be playing Destiny, The Last of Us, Call of Duty etc. I am happy if I can save one game's worth data in a 12GB console - I can simply start and finish a game and then carry on with another one.

Comment: As long as you use games on disks, the only data that's saved on the hard drive is game saves and patches, if any. 10 GB should be more than enough for a lot of games, imho. I hope someone with actual console experience can confirm.

Comment: @Chippies large updates, DLC, and game saves can easily take up more than 10GB. I think my Skyrim saves alone total for more than 10GB (then again, that's many hundreds of saves over several characters).

Answer (score 1):

The 12GB console will not be nearly enough space if you plan to download any games -- definitely don't plan on using your PS Plus free game library, for example.  (I'm looking at a random position in my Download List, showing 4 games, all from PS+, that total well over 20GB between the 4 of them.  There are other games on here that exceed that amount *by themselves*.)

The good news is you can upgrade that console with a cheap drive (I think up to about 1TB?) and have games for days.  As of this writing, you can get a 750GB drive from NewEgg for about $50.  Throw in a $50 year of PS+ and you will never run out of stuff to play, or space to store it.